# shared pointer is shown as expired

Tags: c++, gdb, shared-ptr

While debugging a piece of code I see this on gdb:

```
(gdb) p *(input_t *) 0xec08b4d0
 $25 = {
    count = 0xec0644ec, 
    data = std::shared_ptr (expired, weak 0) 0xec0913ec, 
}
```

Assignment to data leads to a crash. Is data an invalid pointer ?

Comment: Might need to add some code. Code that can reproduce what you see in the debugger will get you the most answers.